# Credit Cards Similar to Co-ops

Tags: credit-card

I keep getting advertisements from BarclayCards Ring and finally clicked on it because it seemed like a different type of credit. It appears to be a credit card that the rewards are based on the community. The research that I've done doesn't seem to reveal much about what type of power the community will have besides "voting" on rewards and sharing in the profits. Not much is said about the actual profits. But the more I thought about it, the more the idea of being able profit for keeping good credit started to attract me

> "to share in the program's profits over time" [source](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052970203458604577263342831722010.html)

I pay off my credit card each month and don't run a balance. It seems like there would be little risk for me to join, but my question is, has this been done somewhere else and what were the results? More specifically, How much would/could profit sharing be? I think I have an idea of how credit card companies work, would the most profitable case be that I pay my credit card off and everyone else that has joined keeps a balance, so the card "profits"?

Thanks,

EDIT: I didn't include the link to the card for fear of this being seen as advertisement for the card.

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"share in the program's profits over time", yet "consumers won't earn rewards points that they can redeem for gift cards, travel or other features." You risk not getting the 2% rebate that seems to be most optimum.
Yes, there are cards that offer higher on select purchases, etc, but it seems 2% on all purchases is about the highest virtually unlimited rebate I've seen. Their potential reward from the WSJ article is pretty vague. 
I see nothing wrong with a link, so long as it's not an affiliate link, just plain vanilla link to Barclay's offer.